# Graph API bad request to create meeting

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a script in Powershell to get teams link using a call to Microsoft API graph. However, I am getting the below error:

> "Invoke-RestMethod : Error en el servidor remoto: (400) Solicitud incorrecta"

This is my script:

```
$tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}
$accessTokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Method POST -Body $body
$accessToken = $accessTokenResponse.access_token
$graphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$userid/onlineMeetings"
$params = @{
    startDateTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse("2023-07-01T14:30:34.2444915-07:00")
    endDateTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse("2023-07-01T15:00:34.2464912-07:00")
    subject = "User Token Meeting"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}
$newMeetingResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphEndpoint -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $params
$joinUrl = $newMeetingResponse.onlineMeeting.joinUrl
Write-Host "Enlace de la reunión: $joinUrl"
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong here?

Error is bad request (400)

> "Invoke-RestMethod : Error en el servidor remoto: (400) Solicitud incorrecta"

Comment: Any reason to have "Content-Type" = "application/json" in $params? Try remove "Content-Type" = "application/json" from $params

Comment: Who is the $userid? Your account? Not clear what you have declared there. Did you make sure your ClientId has OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite permission?

Comment: I resolved the issue removing the line ""Content-Type" = "application/json" and adding "$jsonparams = $params | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4" having the -Body of Invoke-RestMethod as $jsonparams